# How to stop deleting or updating the first comment from notification bar android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer.I create code to see if there are any new comments in my database. It's work fine but I have one problem new I can receive the first comment.But if you receive a second comment, the first comment will be updated and deleted, and the new or second comment will take its place.I do not need to delete the first comment I need to receive all comments to the user.How I con do that?

I need to show them all in case the user has not deleted or opened them In the notification bar.

For example like this image will by show:
[image]

Notifications code:

```
 public void Notification(){
        String url =  "https://xxxxxxxxxx/Notification.php?UId="+UId;
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String id = hit.getString("id");
                           Intent activityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityFargmainMarket.class);
                            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, activityIntent, 0);
                            int lastThread = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id));
                            if (app.getTotal_threadss() <lastThread) {
                                app.setTotal_threadss(lastThread);
                                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
                                        .setContentTitle("title")
                                        .setContentText("text")
                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                        .build();
                                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);


                            }
                        } catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }
```

Comment: store in the db

Comment: and fetch comments from db use room

Comment: and in notification just insert into the db, get a live data from db it will update automatically as well

Comment: from notification bar @vikaskumar

Comment: wherever you are extending from FirebaseMessagingService class. there you will get the comments there only insert into the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android notifications are dependent on the Channel ID. If this is a fixed `CHANNEL_1_ID` android will delete the message with the same ID. You should change the channel id dynamically as you create new push notification. Looking at your code you can use the id value of the comment:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
                                        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
                                        .setContentTitle("title")
                                        .setContentText("text")
                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                                        .build();
                                notificationManager.notify(**id**, notification);
```

Per documentation:
Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been cancelled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Comment: Hello brother, thank you for your response. Actually, this is what I need, but how can I do it? Now I have applied the code you sent to me but it is still being deleted. How can I make a different id each time.

Comment: Hey @Mafo Is the id value you retrieve from your json unique or it is the same everytime? I've edited my answer the different notification id should be set in the notification manager. If this doesn't work you can create a random id to be passed there.

Comment: Awesome! Good luck